# How can I get the firebase UID of my marker when I click the button inside the info window

Tags: android, firebase

I have a long and lat data from my Firebase database and I would like to render those long, lat in my custom google map where the information and a button along with those long, lat are put in the info window when I click the marker. How can I get the UID if I click the button in the info window. or any data from that specific marker info window.

Comment: Please post your code with a minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure i fully understand the question but,

In order for you to get the UID of a firebase user, you can use the method:

```
String userID = FirebaseUser.getUID();
```

You are then free to use this string as you see fit.

Comment: thank you for that, what I need is the UID from the assigned marker or button.